# Error when installing the module BondGraphTools in a virtual environment

Tags: python, bash, terminal, julia, zsh

So basically I went into the official BondGraph [documentation](https://bondgraphtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/installing-on-osx.html) module which tells you how to install it.

So far so good when doing *step 1* and *step 2*.

Here in *step 2* because I am using `zsh` instead of `bash`, I changed the code to

```
$ echo 'export PATH=/Applications/Julia-0.6.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/:$PATH' >> ~/.zshenv
```

right here, I am not sure if this is the correct path or if I should be using  `~/.zprofile`  or  `.zshrc`.

Then I open my virtual environment called `sist_dinamicos` located in `~/Others/PyEnvironments` and attempt *step 3*, where I try to install the module but I get below errors:

[image: error 1]

[image: error 2]

Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: It's not entirely clear that https://github.com/BondGraphTools/BondGraphTools is still actively developed or maintained; the Julia version that it's depending on, v0.6.4, has not been supported for some time (current stable is v1.5.2).

Comment: So do you think this could be the answer to the error?

Comment: That would be my guess, but even so someone else might be able to direct you to a workable fix